# RecyclerView not populating

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to populate a recyclerview from within an another recyclerview adapter. Something is wrong with the `rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context))` the code is breaking at this line the console output is:

```
08-17 21:14:20.221 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-17 21:14:20.227 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@85153aa
08-17 21:14:20.228 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@19a9b9b
08-17 21:14:20.230 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-17 21:14:20.237 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f1fab38
08-17 21:14:20.237 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@bf72711
08-17 21:14:20.239 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-17 21:14:20.244 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@e490076
08-17 21:14:20.244 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@47d5677
08-17 21:14:20.247 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-17 21:14:20.253 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@c042e4
08-17 21:14:20.253 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@696234d
08-17 21:14:20.255 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-17 21:14:20.260 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@73cae02
08-17 21:14:20.261 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@966e313
08-17 21:14:20.263 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-17 21:14:20.266 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@db0a950
08-17 21:14:20.266 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@baea749
08-17 21:14:20.267 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-17 21:14:40.197 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                       --------- beginning of crash
08-17 21:14:40.198 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: in.co.servicedeal.app, PID: 11999
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at in.co.servicedeal.app.adapter.BrandAdapter$1.onClick(BrandAdapter.java:106)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)


                                                                       --------- beginning of system
08-17 21:14:40.201 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
08-17 21:14:40.242 11999-11999/in.co.sd.app I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11999 SIG: 9
```

**Adapter Code**

```
public class BrandAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<BrandBean> brandList;
    private RecyclerView rv;


    public BrandAdapter(final Context context, final ArrayList<BrandBean> brandList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.brandList = brandList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return brandList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return brandList.get(i).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_brand_service_grid, null);

            //Grid Text
            final TextView gridText = view.findViewById(R.id.brand_grid_text);
            gridText.setText(brandList.get(i).getServiceType());

            //Grid Arraw
            final ImageView gridArrow = view.findViewById(R.id.brand_grid_arrow);

            gridArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Grid Dropdown
                    rv = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_SI);

                    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                    getProductDetailsByProductId(brandList.get(i).getId());
                }
            });
        }
        return view;
    }
```

The idea is to achieve this layout :

[image]

Where the white space will contain the recyclerView content in it.

Comment: Probaby this line returns a null object _rv = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_SI);_

Comment: Yes, I see in the log, but don't know why, I have instantiated the recyclerView just above that line.

Comment: Do you have the ViewHolder classes? Also why are you extending BaseAdapter instead for RecyclerView.Adapter?

Comment: Actually I have view like this : GridView > RecyclerView > RecyclerView.

Comment: So, to populate the GridView I have created a adapter class which extends BaseAdapter and from with in this adapter class I have to populate a recyclerView for which I have a adapter class which extends "RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting null pointer exception because the name of your view in Onclick method is same as the name of the view in a getView method, so the view's  onclick method overrides your parent view, that's why you are getting error. 
To avoid null pointer exception just change onclick view name i.e

```
view1.gridArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View **view1**) {
                    //Grid Dropdown
                    rv = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_SI);

                    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                    getProductDetailsByProductId(brandList.get(i).getId());
                }
            });
```

**Suggestion**: You can use ExpandableListView for your requirement, It is easily manageable.